# Limit method parameter values

Tags: java, methods, annotation-processing

Im currently learning about annotation processing in Java.
For the source generation i am writing a small library. Currently i have all modifiers that can be applied to methods or fields (final, static, transient, synchronized ....) in a single enum. My generation library provides a method addModifiers(ModifierEnum... modifiers) and is inherited by the Field-Element and the Method-Element from their superclass.

I was wondering if there is some way to limit the values that are allowed to be passed to the method depending on element it is called on.
I first thought of overriding the method in each type or adding a validation method and throwing an exception if the parameters contain an invalid combination or value, but this would only be a runtime solution. A compile time solution would be extremely neat but i doubt it is possible (Maybe also through annotation processing and annotations on the parameter in each element?) since the values passed aren't known until runtime, unless constants are passed to the method (can you limit it to constants only?).

Any ideas?

Comment: "wondering if there is some way to limit the values that are allowed to be passed to the method depending on element it is called on" - Do you know already exactly what number of arguments you need for FieldElement & MethodElement?
Can you note down the signuature? Then we can think of a way to propogate it to parent, if possible. Right now its ambiguous.

Comment: @ImGroot Well Javasyntax defines that each modifier can only be applied once to the same element and what modifiers can be applied in which combination to what element. So for my Mehtod-Element for instance i know what subset of my Modifier enum may be passed to the method in which combination and each enum only once.